# QGIS 3.20 failed dependency in qgis_core on libQt5Concurrent

Tags: qgis, mac, python-3, anaconda, pyinstaller

I wrote a Python application that successfully uses QGIS on OSX. I now want to *'freeze'* it. Building an app after using the `kyngchaos` packages resulted in all sorts of issues finding components. I switched to using `pyinstaller` in Anaconda.

I created a Python 3.8 environment and installed QGIS with:

```
conda install qgis --channel conda-forge
```

I had to tell pyinstaller to find some hidden components:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "./User:./User" --add-data "./URSA:./URSA" --hidden-import PyQt5.QtSql --hidden-import PyQt5.QtNetwork --hidden-import PyQt5.QtXml UVANDA
```

That eliminated all of the missing components errors.

I'm now getting this response:

```
(UVANDA-latest) Praha:UVANDA kovar$ ./UVANDA 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UVANDA", line 14, in <module>
  File "/Users/kovar/opt/anaconda3/envs/UVANDA-latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "URSA/UVANDA/Gui/UApplication.py", line 26, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsApplication
  File "/Users/kovar/opt/anaconda3/envs/UVANDA-latest/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "qgis/core/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/kovar/work/build/UVANDA/dist/UVANDA/qgis/_core.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/libQt5Concurrent.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/kovar/work/build/UVANDA/dist/UVANDA/qgis_core
  Reason: Incompatible library version: qgis_core requires version 5.12.0 or later, but libQt5Concurrent.5.dylib provides version 5.9.0
```

when I run the app in the dist directory.

I'm unable to figure out how to get anaconda to install a more current version of `libQt5Concurrent`, if that is even the issue.